# How to build postman request for Rails POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, postman

No matter how I format the raw portion of this request, I cannot avoid the parsing error below.

I have a Rails API with a create method that passes the spec, to illustrate that the controller message is sound:

```
describe "POST power_up" do

    let!(:client) { FactoryGirl.create :client, name: "joe", auth_token: "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf" }

    it "should create and save a new Power Up" do

      expect { post :create, format: :json, power_up: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:power_up) }.to change(V1::PowerUp, :count).by(1)
    end

  end
```

I'm using Postman to try to POST to it.  No matter what I try I'm getting the error:

```
Started POST "/v1/power_ups.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-30 18:05:29 -0400
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

{
  'name': 'foo',
  'description': 'bar'
}


ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at '{
  'name': 'foo',
  'description': 'bar'
}
```

Postman request setup:

[image: screen cap of postman request]

I've also tried:

```
{
  'power_up': {
    'name': 'foo',
    'description': 'bar'
   }
}
```

Code from create method and strong parameters declaration in `power_ups_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    @power_up = PowerUp.new(power_up_params)

  if @power_up.save!
    redirect_to @power_up
  end
end

private

  def power_up_params
    params.require(:power_up).permit(:name, :description)
  end
```

Answer (score 14):

Sorry bit too late to answer this but might help someone else.

All you need to do is `-` in your request header (in postman or whatever client)  add

```
Content-Type = 'application/json'
```

Alternatively, you can also try it with curl (source):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"power_up": {
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "bar"
   }
}' 127.0.01:3000/v1/power_ups.json
```

Comment: I always forget to add the `Content-Type: application/json` when using raw-json body. If not set, my params aren't present (in Rails controller) Thanks for the answer, this one gets me a lot!

Answer (score 11):

Like **@Tejas Patel** said it's all about headers. But instead of setting them explicitly you can just:

1.- In the request creation area switch to the `body` tab. Set `raw` radio button. In the lower text area input your body:

```
{
  "power_up": {
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "bar"
   }
}
```

2.- Then in a dropdown list to the rigth choose `JSON (application/json)` option instead of the default `Text` option. That will auto-set the required headers. That's it - you can press "Send" button.

Answer (score 7):

Single quotes (') are not actually the legal [string delimiter](http://json.org) in JSON: a string must be enclosed in double quotes ("). You can get away with it in the browser, since they are string delimiters in javascript. You can easily replicate this in an irb session

```
JSON.parse(%q[{'foo': 'bar'}]) #=> raises JSON::ParserError
JSON.parse(%q[{"foo": "bar"}]) #=> ok
```

In addition, given your spec you should be using the second form i.e.

```
{
  "power_up": {
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "bar"
   }
}
```

Comment: You've moved me closer it appears.  However I get the following: `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: power_up):`.  I also tried to remove the enclosing curly brackets.

Comment: That means the data doesn't match the strong parameter requirements your controller has setup.

Comment: I've added the strong params and create methods above.  There is a quirk, that `PowerUp` is within a module `V1`.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Looking at the log file might be interesting, to see how rails parsed this (it should be "power_up" => {"name" => "foo", "description" => "bar"}

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  When I do the request as you recommend, there is no statement in the log that shows the incoming param values.  However if I use form values, I can get `Parameters: {"name"=>"foo", "description"=>"bar"}`, however I don't see a way in postman to assign the form to a `power_up` object.